# What is the symbol for split-complex numbers?

Tags: notation, split-complex-numbers

$\mathbb{R}$ is the set of the real numbers, $\mathbb{C}$ is the set of the complex numbers, but is there also a symbol for the split-complex numbers?

Comment: Neither the wikipedia article, nor the references therein, nor the questions on this site tagged with split complex numbers give a conventional notation.

Comment: $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown See my answer.

Comment: I had not heard of this ring, but it is $\mathbb{R}[x]/ (x^2 -1)$, so you could just call it that.

Comment: If up to isomorphism, then $\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 3):

The letter $D$, either plain or in blackboard bold ($\mathbb D$), denotes these numbers. The D stands for "double number", an alternative name (the split-complex numbers have been given many names).

An example of this usage is [Antonuccio (1994)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9311032v2.pdf):

> An informal yet instructive way of introducing the complex number system $\mathbb C$ to a newcomer is to postulate the existence of 'numbers' having the form
>   $$z = x + iy\tag{1.1}$$
>   where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers and $i$ is a commuting variable satisfying the relation
>   $$i^2=-1.\tag{1.2}$$
>   If we write $i^2=+1$ instead of $i^2=-1$, what kind of number system do we end
>   up with? To explore this possibility we will consider 'numbers' of the form
>   $$w = t + jx \tag{1.3}$$
>   where $t$ and $x$ are real and $j$ is a commuting variable satisfying the relation
>   $$j^2 = +1\tag{1.4}$$
>   The algebra defined by $(1.3)$ and $(1.4)$ will be denoted by the symbol $D$…

Answer (score 2):

Another notation is $\Bbb C'$, but I'm not sure how standard it is. Although in general one can take $\alpha,\beta\in \Bbb R$ and set $$\Bbb C_{\alpha,\beta} =\{a+b\mathfrak{u}\mid a,b\in\Bbb R\mbox{ and } \mathfrak{u}^2=\alpha+\beta\mathfrak{u}\},$$so that $\Bbb C_{-1,0} =\Bbb C$, $\Bbb C_{1,0} = \Bbb C'$, etc.. The safe way to proceed when writing is to choose a notation, explain it in the beginning of your text, and use it consistently.

Answer (score 1):

It is $\mathbb{D}$ as in here:

[image]

Image source: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.527.356&rep=rep1&type=pdf

But for many it may be confusing, for instance some may thing it means dual numbers.

Comment: Why is the downvote?